# How can a store raw JSON in Mongo using Spring Boot

Tags: json, mongodb, spring-boot

I'd like to take HTTP PUT request with JSON and store it unmodified in Mongo. How can I do this? The best I have is this:

```
@RestController
public class ConfigurationController {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @RequestMapping
    public DBObject index() {
        return mongoTemplate.getCollection("foo").findOne();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    ResponseEntity<?> add(@RequestBody DBObject object) {

        mongoTemplate.insert(object, "foo");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 25):

In newer versions of Mongodb (mongo-java-driver 3.0+) the API uses org.bson.Document, so your solution should look like this:

```
@RestController
public class ConfigurationController {

   @Autowired
   private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
   ResponseEntity<?> add(@RequestBody String jsonString) {

       Document doc = Document.parse(jsonString)
       mongoTemplate.insert(doc, "foo");

       return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.CREATED);
   }

}
```

Comment: Will it update the document if I set id in the json?

Answer (score 3):

Not maybe nicest solution, but something like this should work - change controller to accept any string:

```
... add(@RequestBody String object) ...
```

and follow http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-convert-json-data-to-dbobject/

```
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **json-simple lib**, it has small and elegant json object and use it in your model POJO and it will be converted to mongo Object type automatically

```
private JSONObject jsonSettings;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps, if you have option to create a Map in your Document then create it and later populate the "key-value" pairs in the hash map and store it. It will be stored as you expect (which is a JSON). This will be helpful when you do not know the name of the key or value during compile time.

Answer (score 0):

To store raw json object/array, all you have to do is to declare the type as "Object" in the Pojo and/or DTO level on your server side.

The "Object" type will work with Spring Data and MapStruct too.

Then on the client side, you can send your json data as a json data.